# Cannot filter content out of a string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get the content `Camp de Futbol d'Aixovall` in this string:

```
//<![CDATA[        

//document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {mapsLoad()});
Event.observe(window, 'load', mapsLoad);   

function loadMarkers()
{
    setMarker(
      "Camp de Futbol d'Aixovall", 
      42.476449269018,
      1.487649679184,
      null,
      null,
      1996,
      null, 
      null, 
      null, 
      null,
      "/venues/andorra/devk-arena/v1996/"
    );
}

 //]]>
```

I tried this regex pattern: `loadMarkers[^\{]+(.*})`

but this won't work, someone could help me?

**update**

```
var name = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex
            .Match(c, @"(?<=function\s+loadMarkers\([^()]*\)(?:\r?\n.*){2}\r?\n\s*")[^ "]+(?=")").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: What is the tool?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I used this tool for test the regex: https://regex101.com/

Comment: What good is using a regex tester if you won't be able to use the regex in the target environment? Where will you be using the pattern? And what are the actual requirements?

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, I misunderstand your question, I'm using c# as environment

Comment: Then do not use regex101, use RegexStorm.net.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this will return 0 matches found in about 0 milliseconds.

Comment: Try [this one](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=function%5cs%2bloadMarkers%5c%28%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%5c%29%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn.*%29%7b2%7d%5cr%3f%5cn%5cs*%22%28%5b%5e%22%5d%2b%29%22&i=%2f%2f%3c!%5bCDATA%5b++++++++%0d%0a%0d%0a%2f%2fdocument.observe%28%22dom%3aloaded%22%2c+function%28%29+%7bmapsLoad%28%29%7d%29%3b%0d%0aEvent.observe%28window%2c+%27load%27%2c+mapsLoad%29%3b+++%0d%0a%0d%0afunction+loadMarkers%28%29%0d%0a%7b%0d%0a++++setMarker%28%0d%0a++++++%22Camp+de+Futbol+d%27Aixovall%22%2c+%0d%0a++++++42.476449269018%2c%0d%0a++++) (the value is in Group 1).

Comment: Or [this one](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dfunction%5cs%2bloadMarkers%5c%28%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%5c%29%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn.*%29%7b2%7d%5cr%3f%5cn%5cs*%22%29%5b%5e%22%5d%2b%28%3f%3d%22%29&i=%2f%2f%3c!%5bCDATA%5b++++++++%0d%0a%0d%0a%2f%2fdocument.observe%28%22dom%3aloaded%22%2c+function%28%29+%7bmapsLoad%28%29%7d%29%3b%0d%0aEvent.observe%28window%2c+%27load%27%2c+mapsLoad%29%3b+++%0d%0a%0d%0afunction+loadMarkers%28%29%0d%0a%7b%0d%0a++++setMarker%28%0d%0a++++++%22Camp+de+Futbol+d%27Aixovall%22%2c+%0d%0a++++++42.476449269018%2c%0d%0a++++) (the text is in the returned match value).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the last working, but I have some problem with the `"` because c# think that I'm closing the string

Comment: Both are working. Post the code you are trying to put it in (just update the question)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the exact string as you posted, you may use the following regex

```
function\s+loadMarkers\([^()]*\)(?:\r?\n.*){2}\r?\n\s*"([^"]+)"
```

and extract Group 1 value. See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=function%5cs%2bloadMarkers%5c%28%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%5c%29%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn.*%29%7b2%7d%5cr%3f%5cn%5cs*%22%28%5b%5e%22%5d%2b%29%22&i=%2f%2f%3c!%5bCDATA%5b++++++++%0d%0a%0d%0a%2f%2fdocument.observe%28%22dom%3aloaded%22%2c+function%28%29+%7bmapsLoad%28%29%7d%29%3b%0d%0aEvent.observe%28window%2c+%27load%27%2c+mapsLoad%29%3b+++%0d%0a%0d%0afunction+loadMarkers%28%29%0d%0a%7b%0d%0a++++setMarker%28%0d%0a++++++%22Camp+de+Futbol+d%27Aixovall%22%2c+%0d%0a++++++42.476449269018%2c%0d%0a++++).

**Details**

- `function\s+loadMarkers\(` - this matches `function`, 1+ whitespaces, `loadMarkers(`,
- `[^()]*` - matches any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `(?:\r?\n.*){2}` - matches a line break and the whole line, two times (skipping two lines this way)
- `\r?\n` - a line break
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `"` - a double quote
- `([^"]+)` - Group 1: any 1+ chars other than `"`
- `"` - a double quote.

In C#, the code will look like

```
var pattern = @"function\s+loadMarkers\([^()]*\)(?:\r?\n.*){2}\r?\n\s*""([^""]+)""";
var name = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(c, pattern).Groups[1].Value;
```

The result will be `Camp de Futbol d'Aixovall`. See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dfunction%5cs%2bloadMarkers%5c%28%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%5c%29%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn.*%29%7b2%7d%5cr%3f%5cn%5cs*%22%29%5b%5e%22%5d%2b%28%3f%3d%22%29&i=%2f%2f%3c!%5bCDATA%5b++++++++%0d%0a%0d%0a%2f%2fdocument.observe%28%22dom%3aloaded%22%2c+function%28%29+%7bmapsLoad%28%29%7d%29%3b%0d%0aEvent.observe%28window%2c+%27load%27%2c+mapsLoad%29%3b+++%0d%0a%0d%0afunction+loadMarkers%28%29%0d%0a%7b%0d%0a++++setMarker%28%0d%0a++++++%22Camp+de+Futbol+d%27Aixovall%22%2c+%0d%0a++++++42.476449269018%2c%0d%0a++++).

If, for some reason, you want to get the result as a whole match value, wrap the left and right hand contexts in lookarounds:

```
var pattern = @"(?<=function\s+loadMarkers\([^()]*\)(?:\r?\n.*){2}\r?\n\s*"")[^""]+(?="")";
var name = Regex.Match(c, pattern).Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can also use the pattern

```
(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)
```

which matches a position between a prefix and a suffix. It yields the `find` value directly without having to use groups.

```
(?<=function\sloadMarkers\(\)\s+\{\s+setMarker\(\s+")[^"]+(?=")
```

where

```
prefix = function\sloadMarkers\(\)\s+\{\s+setMarker\(\s+"
find = [^"]+
suffix = "
```